# Creating multiple text box user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I'm trying to build a UserControl that will allow the user to as much TextBoxes as he needed.

**My Process:**

1. The user sees a "+" button
2. Clicking on that button will add a new text box below current text box
3. Each text box will have the name of: "name_numberOfTextBox". e.g: first will be "textbox_1", second "textbox_2" etc..

**My Problems:**

1. .Net is messing with my names when rendering the page, adding "myControlName" to each name..
2. .Net is messing with my Ids - it gives different ids to each TextBox which make it impossible for my to use Page.FindControl method in order to the get text TextBox
3. On each click on the "+" button, it adds a new TextBox but remove the content that was already entered in the previous TextBox (since page life cycle is called again).

**This is my code:**

```
public partial class MultipleTextBox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    private readonly string SESSION_TEXTBOX_LIST = "textboxList";

    private readonly string SESSION_NAME = "multipleTextBoxName";

    private List<TextBox> textBoxList;

    private string name;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            btnRemove.Visible = false;
            Session[SESSION_TEXTBOX_LIST] = null;
            Session[SESSION_NAME] = null;
            textBoxList = new List<TextBox>();
            Session[SESSION_TEXTBOX_LIST] = textBoxList;
            return;
        }
        if (Session[SESSION_NAME] != null)
            name = (string)Session[SESSION_NAME];
        if (Session[SESSION_TEXTBOX_LIST] != null)
            textBoxList = (List<TextBox>)Session[SESSION_TEXTBOX_LIST];
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxList.Add(createTextBox());
        ShowTextboxes();
        btnRemove.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)container.FindControl(name + "_" + textBoxList.Count);
        textBoxList.Remove(textBox);
        container.Controls.Remove(textBox);
    }

    private TextBox createTextBox()
    {
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        textbox.Attributes["name"] = name + "_" + (textBoxList.Count + 1);
        textbox.Attributes["id"] = name + "_" + (textBoxList.Count + 1);
        return textbox;
    }

    private void ShowTextboxes()
    {
        if (textBoxList == null || name == null)
            return;
        foreach (TextBox textBox in textBoxList)
        {
            container.Controls.Add(textBox);
            container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot help you with your code if you don't have any code. Give it a try and ask when you encounter problems. Don't forget to post your code then.

Comment: @nvoigt thanks for your comment, the code has been added :)